# Mutally exclusive bean loading

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot and would like to conditionally load two beans based of what profile is passed.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("secure")
public class Secured ... //this should only load when "secure" is supplied

@Configuration
public class NotSecured ... //this should be the default
```

So basically:

If the user passed `--spring.profiles.active=secured` I want the Secured bean to load but not the NotSecured bean.  By default it should just load the NotSecured bean.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by user passed `--spring.profiles.active=secured` ?

Comment: That is how to set the current profile in a spring application, by user I mean other developers.

Comment: @minion well according to the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profiles) that is how you do it.  but it does not work.

Comment: when you meant by user passed, i took it literally. That is the confusion about my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the '!' not operator, i.e. annotate the Bean/Configuration class with `@Profile("!secure")` and it will only be used when the 'secure' profile is not active.

Answer (score 0):

You may also specify the default profile setting with this annotation explicitly:

- `@Profile("default")`
- or with a value like `@Profile({"insecure","default"}`

It's worth noting that **any bean that does not specify a profile belongs to the default profile**.

It surprised me to find that if you have several implementations for a service and one is annotated with `@Primary` and `@Profile(...)` the bean with the **default profile will get injected** if the profile *is not* configured (*example configuration `applications.properties`:* `spring.profiles.active=val1,val2,...`).

Said differently, when `@Profile` is used in any implementation, the `@Primary` annotation doesn't appear to be considered; and if no profile is defined, the *default* will be used (which could be an implementation without the `@Profile` annotation since that one becomes the default!).

```xml
<!-- Tested for -->
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
```